# An internal error occurred during: "JBoss Tools Project Validator"

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss

I am using **Eclipse Kepler Service Release 2** since about one week I experience problems with **JBoss Tools Project Validator**. The issue happens while cleaning the projects.

Looking at the logs, it looks like a cycling dependency:

> *java.lang.StackOverflowError     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.SourceType.getPackageFragment(SourceType.java:427)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.NamedMember.getFullyQualifiedName(NamedMember.java:183)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.SourceType.getFullyQualifiedName(SourceType.java:272)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.SourceType.getFullyQualifiedName(SourceType.java:265)
>     at
>   org.jboss.tools.common.java.ParametedType.equals(ParametedType.java:161)
>     at
>   org.jboss.tools.common.java.ParametedType.isAssignableTo(ParametedType.java:380)
>     at
>   org.jboss.tools.common.java.ParametedType.areTypeParametersAssignableTo(ParametedType.java:430)
>     at
>   org.jboss.tools.common.java.ParametedType.isAssignableTo(ParametedType.java:398)
>     at
>   org.jboss.tools.common.java.ParametedType.isAssignableTo(ParametedType.java:402)
>     at
>   org.jboss.tools.common.java.ParametedType.areTypeParametersAssignableTo(ParametedType.java:430)
>     at
>   org.jboss.tools.common.java.ParametedType.isAssignableTo(ParametedType.java:398)
>     at
>   org.jboss.tools.common.java.ParametedType.isAssignableTo(ParametedType.java:402)
>     at
>   org.jboss.tools.common.java.ParametedType.areTypeParametersAssignableTo(ParametedType.java:430)
>     at
>   org.jboss.tools.common.java.ParametedType.isAssignableTo(ParametedType.java:398)
>     at
>   org.jboss.tools.common.java.ParametedType.isAssignableTo(ParametedType.java:402)
>     at
>   org.jboss.tools.common.java.ParametedType.areTypeParametersAssignableTo(ParametedType.java:430)
>     at
>   org.jboss.tools.common.java.ParametedType.isAssignableTo(ParametedType.java:398)
>     at
>   org.jboss.tools.common.java.ParametedType.isAssignableTo(ParametedType.java:402)ava.lang.StackOverflowError
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.SourceType.getPackageFragment(SourceType.java:427)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.NamedMember.getFullyQualifiedName(NamedMember.java:183)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.SourceType.getFullyQualifiedName(SourceType.java:272)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.SourceType.getFullyQualifiedName(SourceType.java:265)
>     at
>   org.jboss.tools.common.java.ParametedType.equals(ParametedType.java:161)
>     at
>   org.jboss.tools.common.java.ParametedType.isAssignableTo(ParametedType.java:380)
>     at
>   org.jboss.tools.common.java.ParametedType.areTypeParametersAssignableTo(ParametedType.java:430)
>     at
>   org.jboss.tools.common.java.ParametedType.isAssignableTo(ParametedType.java:398)
>     at
>   org.jboss.tools.common.java.ParametedType.isAssignableTo(ParametedType.java:402)
>     at
>   org.jboss.tools.common.java.ParametedType.areTypeParametersAssignableTo(ParametedType.java:430)
>     at
>   org.jboss.tools.common.java.ParametedType.isAssignableTo(ParametedType.java:398)
>     at
>   org.jboss.tools.common.java.ParametedType.isAssignableTo(ParametedType.java:402) ...*

At the end of the log file:

> *at org.jboss.tools.cdi.internal.core.impl.CDIProject.containsType(CDIProject.java:498)
>     at
>   org.jboss.tools.cdi.internal.core.impl.CDIProject.getBeans(CDIProject.java:383)
>     at
>   org.jboss.tools.cdi.internal.core.validation.CDICoreValidator.validateInjectionPoint(CDICoreValidator.java:1805)
>     at
>   org.jboss.tools.cdi.internal.core.validation.CDICoreValidator.validateBean(CDICoreValidator.java:742)
>     at
>   org.jboss.tools.cdi.internal.core.validation.CDICoreValidator.validateResource(CDICoreValidator.java:611)
>     at
>   org.jboss.tools.cdi.internal.core.validation.CDICoreValidator.validateAll(CDICoreValidator.java:511)
>     at
>   org.jboss.tools.common.validation.ValidatorManager.validateAll(ValidatorManager.java:132)
>     at
>   org.jboss.tools.common.validation.ValidatorManager.validateInJob(ValidatorManager.java:84)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.validation.internal.operations.ValidatorJob.run(ValidatorJob.java:78)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)*

Unfortuantely I can't find any cycling dependancy in my xhtml pages or Java classes. Any idea how to solve this ?

After reply from Viacheslav Kabanovich I could just find sth. like this which I can't imagine to be the problem... in my case there are heaps of this constellations in the code... also it is not exactely the combination he meant...

```
@Named
public class A extends B<Y,Z> implements Serializable
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 4283839282383928L;
@Inject
private transient C<Y,Z> c;
....
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced the problem with this fake bean:

```
public class A<V extends A.B> {

    static class B extends A<V> {       
    }

    @Inject
    A<V> s2; 
}
```

I would like to see an example from 'real life'. Could you please find in your code an injection that sets a parameter type to a variable and post it here with type declarations of bean class that is assignable to it?

Anyway, it is a bug for us to fix.

Added on Nov 19:
I have created issue https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-21036 and fixed cases which I could find. 
Please add in a comment to the issue cases that involve type parameters. The set of definitions should be complete, for instance please add in your example for B and C declarations of types B and C, and if they extend other types and declare type parameters with boundaries, declarations of all involved types are needed.

Comment: I had a look at it, but it's very hard to find as the Project consists of hundreds of classes... the first quick scan just revealed the one I edited above...

Comment: is there a way to find the classes which causes this issue ?

Comment: I am now pretty sure that above code is causing the problem... as I deleted the injected parameter type variable , the validation on this class completed without warnings....

Answer (score 0):

Try to update to Eclipse Mars + JBoss Tools 4.3.0.